# Extracting grid polygon that are completely filled with a raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I have a gridded polygon in WGS84 geographic coordinates (courser resolution i.e. approximately 6 km), and a raster (finer resolution i.e. approximately 500 meters) also in WGS84. Now I want to extract/clip only those polygons that are completely filled with the raster (yellow color). So the result will be a clipped polygon which will only contain grids that were completely filled with the raster.
How can I do this ArcGIS desktop?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `Raster to Polygon` tool to create a polygon of the raster area. Then use `Select by Location` to select the grid polygons that are completely inside the just-created polygon. Finally, use the `Copy Features` tool to create a new feature class of the selected grid polygons.